Adding a match type to a foreign key with EF Core and Npgsql
When creating a foreign key that references multiple nullable columns in Postgresql it's possible to add a match type of "MATCH FULL" on the foreign key to ensure that all values are either null, or are all required.
Is it possible to do this when creating the foreign key using Entity Framework Core?
For example given the relationship:
entity.HasOne(static e => e.Unit)
    .WithMany(static e => e.Rules)
    .HasForeignKey(static e => new
    {
        e.OwnerId,
        e.UnitId,
    })
    .HasPrincipalKey(static e => new
    {
        e.OwnerId,
        e.Id,
    });

this would generate the DDL:
CONSTRAINT "FK_Rules_Units_OwnerId_UnitId" 
FOREIGN KEY ("OwnerId","UnitId") 
REFERENCES public."Units"("OwnerId","Id"),

but the desired output for this would be
CONSTRAINT "FK_Rules_Units_OwnerId_UnitId" 
FOREIGN KEY ("OwnerId","UnitId") 
REFERENCES public."Units"("OwnerId","Id")
MATCH FULL,

Is it possible to do this using the EntityTypeBuilder and related extension methods, or is the only way to do this to make a custom migration which re-creates that foreign key using raw SQL? It would be preferable to avoid raw SQL as this won't be taken into account by Entity Framework when it creates future migrations.

Don't avoid SQL for DDL. EF migrations are a very simple tool primarily meant for rapid development. They're no substitute for proper database design, schema versioning or a solid migration strategy. ORMs in general aren't database replacements and don't even try to be full DB management libraries. Besides, more than 1 application is going to use the same database, especially in PostgreSQL.

Can you please open an issue requesting this in the github repo? As @PanagiotisKanavos writes above, when EF can't produce the DDL you need, you can drop down to using SQL in your migrations - though I definitely wouldn't go as far as saying EF migrations are primarily meant for rapid development; they do cover a large majority of real-world cases, but there's no way they can cover 100% of possible DDLs for all databases, and SQL support is there for that.

@ShayRojansky a lot of important optimizations can't be expressed using migrations (compression, columnstore indexes, change tracking, non-vanilla indexes). BTW now you're here, if I could find the equivalent of change tracking and columnstore indexes in PostgreSQL, I'd ditch SQL Server.

@ShayRojansky thank you, that's done. It was created at #3198

@RobertDavey thank you - I'll try to get this into 9.0.

@PanagiotisKanavos compression specifically can be configured via EF. Sure, a lot is missing, but I'm honestly not seeing people depend on these advanced things so much (see how low the vote count on these issues on the repos are in general).

My main point here was mainly that it's not either/or, i.e. use migration for everything that does work, and where something's missing, just drop down to SQL for that only.

Regardless of EF... I know some specific editions/versions of PG support columnar storage (e.g.Citus), you may want to look into those. Otherwise I'm not sure what you're referring to with change tracking...

@ShayRojansky transparent compression isn't same as application-side compression. Change tracking is this which allows me to write FROM SalesLT.Product AS P RIGHT OUTER JOIN CHANGETABLE(CHANGES SalesLT.Product, @last_synchronization_version) AS CT ON  P.ProductID = CT.ProductID; to get new, modified or even deleted rows. 1M lighter than CDC.  Several SO questions ask for the equivalents. People may not be voting for these because they don't know them

@ShayRojansky you may have noticed how .... territorial .... database developers can get.

@PanagiotisKanavos ah thanks, I wasn't aware of SQL Server change tracking - I'm definitely not aware of anything like that in PG; the thing to do there is logical replication (full-blown CDC) which is more powerful but also more complex, of course.
